# render javascript function return with links inside

Tags: node.js, pug

I am using this code in a .jade file, inside a for loop to iterate and render html with a object's values:

```
- var linkExist = function(i){
-   if (result[i]){
-       var html = ',follow on ' + i + ': <a href="' + result[i] + '" target="_blank">' + result[i].split("http://")[1] + '</a>';
-       return html;
-   };
- }


#{linkExist('Twitter')}
#{linkExist('GitHub')}
```

It adds extra comments and renders a extra `<` before na d a `>` after, like

```
&lt;
,follow on Twitter: 
<a href="http://twitter.com/user" target="_blank">twitter.com/user</a>
&gt;
<!--,follow on Twitter: <a href="http://twitter.com/user" target="_blank"-->
twitter.com/user
&gt;
&lt;
,follow on GitHub: 
<a href="http://github.com/user" target="_blank">github.com/user</a>
&gt;
<!--,follow on GitHub: <a href="http://github.com/user" target="_blank"-->
github.com/user
&gt;
```

btw, if I use

```
=linkExist('Twitter')
or
| #{linkExist('Twitter')}
```

It renders html as text, but the correct content. (but as text, not html)

Comment: Are you sure your code looks *exactly* the way it appears here?

Comment: @Tomalak, yes, that is the code I am using. Just changed the rendered html user name to "user" on posting here.

Comment: @Tomalak, made a fiddle in case it helps. Didn't get it to render anything from the function though... http://fiddlesalad.com/jade/jade-function-return/

Comment: @Tomalak, found a solution. Thank you for asking and making be double check more things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it,

jade escapes the html automatically. To avoid that one can use `!=`.

So I changed to:

```
- var linkExist = function(i){
-   if (result[i]){
-       var html = ' ,follow on ' + i + ': <a href="' + result[i] + '" target="_blank">' + result[i].split("http://")[1] + '</a>';
-       return html;
-   };
- }


!= linkExist('Twitter')
!= linkExist('GitHub')
```

Comment: +1 for finding out yourself, but you *really* should use some HTML escaping in this case, because this is a potential XSS vulnerability.

Comment: @Tomalak, good point. Hmmm... Asked a new question also thinking about that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927777/re-using-function-inside-jade

Comment: ...and it looks like you got a great answer there. That's how it's supposed to work here. :)