# Re-using function inside jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a inline script and code block repeated 2 times inside a .jade file and would like to:

- re-use it. (i mean DRY it and have just one block/function)
- escape the html like suggested [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924139/render-javascript-function-return-with-links-inside#comment29651522_19925125), right now I am using `!= linkExist('foo')`

My idea was to use `mixin`, but don't know how to. My code works as is, but would like to know how to write it better. Thought about [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (because my code actually works and I just want to improve it) but the jade has not even a tag there yet, so I think SO might be better.

```
h1 Teachers
for result in object.teachers
    - var linkExist = function(i){
    -   if (result[i] != 'undefined'){
    -       var html = ', follow on ' + i + ': <a href="' + result[i] + '" target="_blank">' + result[i].split("http://")[1] + '</a>';
    -       return html;
    -   };
    - }

    section
        h3 #{result.Name} 
        p.inline #{result.Nick}

        img(src=result.img)

        p.small Location: #{result.Location}

        p.small 
            | Web: 
            for webResult in result.Web
                a(href=webResult,target='_blank') #{webResult.split('http://')[1]}

            != linkExist('Twitter')
            != linkExist('GitHub')

//now it repeats the code but for students
h1 Students
for result in object.students
    - var linkExist = function(i){
//etc.......
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a mixin; if you pass `result` as well, it should be pretty generic:

```
mixin linkExist(result, type)
  if result[type] !== undefined
    | , follow on #{type}: <a href="#{result[type]}">...</a>

//- use like this
for result in object.teachers
  ...
  mixin linkExist(result, 'Twitter')
  mixin linkExist(result, 'GitHub')

for result in object.students
  ...
  mixin linkExist(result, 'Twitter')
  mixin linkExist(result, 'GitHub')
```